# Autofocus reset to the beginning of textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, autofocus

When I load (build) the page I have to focus on a textFormField that already has input, but the cursos goes to the beginning of the textfield instead of going to the end of the input.

```
    var _tCelular = TextEditingController();

my init()
        _tCelular.text = "41";



  Container txtCelular1() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _tCelular,
        autofocus: true,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Celular',
          hintText: '(__) _ ____-____',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
          ),
          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _onTapBuscarDadosCliente();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
        focusNode: _focusNodeFone,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          TelefoneInputFormatter(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one was able to help me, I found the answer.
I just had to add `_tCelular.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _tCelular.text.length);` after `_tCelular.text = "41";`

So, my initState is like:

```
_tCelular.text = ddd;

_tCelular.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _tCelular.text.length);
```

That worked for me.